# Shared Access Signature - Signature did not match

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

Getting an error when trying to use a SAS token.

I generate the token on the container like so:

```
var client = _account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference("2017-med");
var sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
{
   Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
   SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(5)
});
```

I append it to the URL of a resource that is in the container and get this error message when I visit the URL:

> Signature did not match. String to sign used was r
>   2023-05-14T05:48:34Z /blob/myblobname/2017-med 2017-07-29

Is it possible to use a container token for resources in the container? Or is there something else at play here?

Answer (score 0):

As I have tested, you search the sasuri in the explorer and the container permission you set is only read.

I suggest that you could add a list permission in your sas policy like below:

```
var sas = container.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
{
   Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read | SharedAccessBlobPermissions.List
   SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.AddYears(5)
});
```

And then when you search it in your explorer you could list all the blob in your container to judge if the sasuri you generated is correct.

The [List Blobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/list-blobs) request may be constructed as follows.
 HTTPS is recommended. Replace myaccount with the name of your storage account:

```
https://myaccount.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?restype=container&comp=list&sastoken
```

Actually, when you generate the sasuri for container, you could use the sasuri to access the blob in the container and do some operations within your permission.

```
string sasUri = uricontainer;
CloudBlockBlob blob = new CloudBlockBlob(new Uri(sasUri));
```

**Update**:

> Signature did not match. String to sign used was r 2023-05-14T05:48:34Z /blob/myblobname/2017-med 2017-07-29

As you have provided, I found that your storagename is **myblobname**, which is very puzzled.

And I found there is **indeed existing the storagename called myblobname**. So, I guess that maybe you have a splicing error.

You could use `var bloburi = container.Uri + sas;` to get the full uri.

And if you want to show list or other operation with full uri, you could refer to the above code I provided.

Comment: @Joe, pay attention to your storage name.Make sure you have add the correct storage  name in uri.